# CK editor 5 is not showing as marked in fronted

Tags: strapi, ckeditor5

Ck-editor 5 is not showing as a markdown in fronted its showing as a string
For example instead of showing

## Header

It's showing

```
<h1>Header</h1>
```

I tried to install CK editor in fronted too
How to solve the issue
I'm using next js as a front end site